# Sql server 2008, are temp tables unique

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, temp-tables

In my server code, I create a temp (named #temp) table, insert some data and then delete the temp table. If more than 1 users were to run this section of the code (creating of the temp table) concurrently, would sql server 2008 create a temp table per user or does it create 1 'global' temp table? If its one table, I assume I would run into trouble when the same table is created more than once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx):

> You can create local and global temporary tables. Local temporary
>   tables are visible only in the current session, and global temporary
>   tables are visible to all sessions
>   ...
>   If a local temporary table is created in a stored procedure or
>   application that can be executed at the same time by several users,
>   the Database Engine must be able to distinguish the tables created by
>   the different users. The Database Engine does this by internally
>   appending a numeric suffix to each local temporary table name. The
>   full name of a temporary table as stored in the sysobjects table in
>   tempdb is made up of the table name specified in the CREATE TABLE
>   statement and the system-generated numeric suffix. To allow for the
>   suffix, table_name specified for a local temporary name cannot exceed
>   116 characters.

Comment: Also from the MSDN  :

Prefix local temporary table names with single number sign (#table_name), and prefix global temporary table names with a double number sign (##table_name).